# PHP Breaking string into smaller form factor

Tags: php

I am busy with an online booking system. After a user selected all his/her seats, the end string to save into my DB looks like this:

> SH1, SH2, SH3, SH4, SH6, SH7, SH8, SI1, SI2, SI3, SI4, SI5, SI7, SP1, SP2, SP3, SQ1, SQ2, SQ3, SQ4, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5

But I need to break it down into something like this:

> SH1-4, SH6-8, SI1-5, SI7, SP1-3, SQ1-4, A1-5

If someone could help me with a short example please.

Comment: And what are rules for such braking?  Once you have 1-4 and once 1-5

Comment: Seats are numbered for example A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, etc. If a users selects seats A2, A3, A4, and A5, I want to convert the displaying of the seats to something short like A2-5 so I need it to follow sequence

Comment: @MattTheNinja I am not trying to split SH1-4, I am trying to shorten SH1, SH2, SH3, SH4 into SH1-4

Comment: Why are you storing that as a string in the database? - if it's a booking system you should surely know what your seats are in advance, the seat number could/should be the primary key. You might then also have a booking table that links seats/tickets to orders and allows your system to quick cross reference bookings against seats... it *looks* like you're breaking every sensible rule of data normalisation going?!

Comment: Answering this would, I suspect, immediately fall foul of : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: HAHAHAHA @MattTheNinja sometimes the simplest tasks boggel a persons mind. This is more needed when printing a ticket for a person then storing in DB. So when printing a ticket, you don't want a massive string with seat numbers, but rather if the seats follow in a sequence, to display the sequence. But Thank you CD001 you gave me the idea that I needed.

Comment: If you have individual records in the DB though you can just iterate over the rows and see when the range changes.

Comment: @chris85 Thank you Chris. Thats exactly what I needed!

Comment: If it's at the *print to invoice* kind of stage then you should be in the application layer rather than the database and it should be a matter of taking your database results (probably as an array or collection) and preforming the manipulation and string formatting before printing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to give a direction, how it can be done.

```
$str="SH1, SH2, SH3, SH4, SH6, SH7, SH8, SI1, SI2, SI3, SI4, SI5, SI7, SP1, SP2, SP3, SQ1, SQ2, SQ3, SQ4, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5";
foreach(explode(', ',$str) as $substr){
    preg_match('#([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)#',$substr,$m);
    $coll[$m[1]][]=$m[2];   
}
$res=[];
foreach($coll as $char => $nums){
    if(count($nums)==1) {
        $res[]="{$char}{$nums[0]}";
    } else {
        foreach($nums as $idx => $num){
            if(@$nums[$idx+1]==$num+1){
               !@$tmp AND $tmp[0]=$num;
               $tmp[1]=$num+1;
            } else if($tmp[0]){
                $res[]="{$char}{$tmp[0]}-$num";
                $tmp=null;
            } else {
                $res[]="{$char}{$num}";
            }
        }
    }
}
print implode(', ',$res);
//RESULT: SH1-4, SH6-8, SI1-5, SI7, SP1-3, SQ1-4, A1-5
```

Making this code failsafe, is on you...

Comment: This is perfect and works like a charm. The only changes I made was do the explode after $str, then do a natsort() to the array, and then in the foreach loop passed the sorted array. But thank you so much!